# Iphone apps and cookies

Tags: iphone, http, cookies, proxy

Is it possible to force all iphone apps to use the same cookies in all http requests ?
Example: i want to send my email in all http requests.

Answer (score 0):

No, not in any supported way. See [NSHTTPCookieStorage](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSHTTPCookieStorage_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

> iOS Note: Cookies are not shared among applications in iOS.

What are you actually trying to accomplish with this?

Comment: ok. 
I have tow iphones that connect to my proxy server and i want in the server side to distinguish between requests sent buy the tow iphones.

Comment: @Bacem That seems like a question about your proxy and its configuration rather than the clients connecting to it. If you want to identify the client I would have each device authenticate to the proxy server as a different user.

Comment: i am using 3g network.
and in 3g configuration you can add only proxy adress.
that meens it's impossible to add login and password in configuration

Comment: @Bacem On an iOS 5.1.1 device you can certainly set authentication settings for a proxy as part of a VPN configuration but if that's not an option for you maybe you can run proxies on multiple ports then and have each device use a different port (assuming this is a small number of personal devices)?

Comment: in wifi connection is possible to configure proxy(@,login,pswd) 
but i am sure that in 3G apn confgiuration it's not possible to configure the login/pswd even in ios 5.1.1.
any way thx for the responses.